Why is the response._id from MongoDB displaying as an object instead of an object ID?
I'm working with MongoDB in a Node.js application using Mongoose. When I retrieve a document from the database and log the _id field, I expect it to be of type ObjectId, as this is the default type for _id in MongoDB. However, when I log the type of response._id using typeof, it shows object:
console.log(typeof response._id); // Output: "object"

The actual value of response._id is something like:
new ObjectId('66f68edc89d2d956b7a2fe7d')

My questions are:
Is ObjectId in MongoDB considered an object in JavaScript?
Shouldn't the type of response._id be ObjectId instead of object?
How can I ensure that the type is treated correctly as ObjectId in my TypeScript code?
Additional details:
I'm using Mongoose in a Node.js environment.
The document retrieval and everything else work fine, but I'm confused about the typeof result.

typeof returns object for any object, see typeof Description
I guess, you are looking for instanceof
console.log(response._id instanceof ObjectId); 

prints true
